# Bash indirect variable reference

Tags: linux, bash, variables

EDIT2: @glenn jackman I thought this would fix it, but it still errs in my full script.  Why isn't it working?  Is it due to the indirect reference?

```
#!/home/$current_user/Desktop/expect
...
    COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt $num ]; do
             let index=COUNTER+1
             tmp=user_$index
             echo "Changing Password for " ${!tmp}
             echo ${!tmp}
             sudo passwd ${!tmp}
             expect -exact "[sudo] password for $current_user: "
             send "$pass\r"
             interact
             expect -exact "New password: "
             send "$password\r"
             interact
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
```

EDIT: The ! or the /$$ works for calling just variables inside of other variables.  I need help for a case where the variable is part of a string.

I had a quick question regarding indirect variable references in Bash.

```
eval "\${user_$index\}"  #First attempt
echo \$${eval "{user_\$index}"} #Second attempt
```

Basically I have several variables named "user_*num*" where the *num* is a integer.  Each of these variables contains a String value.  I want to call that string value by calling the variable.  However, since the variable has a variable inside of it (*num*), I can't seem to get it working.  I've looked through the Man pages for Indirect References in Bash, but  they don't mention cases where the variable inside of another variable is attached to a string.

TLDR: My question is how do you do this:

```
$(var_$num)
```

Comment: Where does `$current_user` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quite awkward in bash: you require a temporary variable to hold the constructed variable name:

```
$ var_1=hello
$ num=1
$ tmp=var_$num
$ echo ${!tmp}
hello
```

Arrays are much simpler

```
$ var=( [1]=world )
$ echo ${var[$num]}
world
```

Comment: Could you help me figure out why the expect portion in the whole script isn't working?  I thought this would fix it.

Comment: Shell and expect are different languages, so you can't mix them up like that. Your shebang line is expect: use expect control structures, conditionals and arithmetic.